# How do you use a Content Provider within a content provider in a CAF?

Tags: webmethods, webmethods-caf

The document response from a webservice contains a list of objects (documents) that contains a list of objects.

eg.

- Name
- Surname
- List of Questions(Questions)

  - Question
  - Required
  - QuestionID
  - List of Answers(Answers)

    - Answer
    - SelectedAnswer
    - AnswerID

I have created a content provider for the List of Questions(Questions) and populated a list, but now I would like a dropdown to be shown within that table using the questions content provider to show the possible answers for that question.

If I just create a seperate content provider for the answers, only the first set of answers are used for each of the questions.

How can I solve this issue?

I have checked this [link](http://tech.forums.softwareag.com/techjforum/posts/list/23858.page) but I am unsure how to implement